# Create a synchronize HTTP GET request in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get some text via HTTP GET and display it to the UI. I do not need an async task (i.e, the user have to wait until I get the text completely).

I tried this in main thread

```
try {
    String url = URL_HERE; 
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet (url);
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    text = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    text = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
}
```

But I always see an exception.
I just need a simple mechanism to get the text. Could you suggest?

Thank you very much,

Comment: please break the suspense,and the exception is...

Comment: That's easy. The exception is probably `NetworkOnMainThreadException` or what's-it-called. Btw: try to avoid catch-alls (`catch(Exception ex)`)

Answer (score 1):

You should use AsyncTask but if you have to use a sync method 
try

String resut  =  execute().get().toString();

it will freeze the UI(without application is not responding) till you got the message from httpget

Answer (score 0):

All networking has to be in a separate thread by Android's design. It is very possible that the request will take some time and the user has to be bothered by waiting as little as possible. So, you *will* have to use an `AsyncTask` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a ASyncTask so the UI thread doesn't freeze. If the UI thread freezes, Android will show an "Application not responding" dialog to the user, so it's important that you do your call in a ASyncTask even if you don't want your user to use the UI while you are doing it.

You can "block" the UI overriding the onPreExecute method in the ASyncTask (to show a progress dialog for example) then "unblock" it overriding the onPostExecute method (to remove the progress dialog for example).

Answer (score 0):

- You should always use `AsyncTask` to perform the network operations
  in android
- Because anything that takes more time to load to the UI will lead to
  `"Unresponsive of the android application"`(ANR)

---

**Sample::**

```
public class FrgLatein extends Fragment {
        //New-Instance
        public static FrgLatein newInstance(){
            Log.d("FrgLatein", "newInstance");
            FrgLatein fragment = new FrgLatein();
            return  fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.d("FrgLatein", "onCreateView");
            View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.frg_latein, container, false);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);


            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.d("FrgLatein", "onActivityCreated");
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            Log.d("FrgLatein", "onStart");
            super.onStart();
            new LongOperation1().execute("");

        }

    private class LongOperation1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                 // Do the Web service long run here
            try {
                 String url = URL_HERE; 
                 HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet (url);
                 ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                 text = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
                }
                catch(Exception ex) {
                text = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
               }
               return "Executed";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
              // Do the UI-task here

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
              // Do the UI-task here
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
              // Do the UI-task here which has to be done during backgroung tasks are running like a downloading process
            }
        }
}
```